# How to install Linux on a fresh HDD in a Mac Mini (2007) - Please help

Tags: system-installation, mac, mac-mini

I had a HDD die in my Mac Mini 2007, I would like to have a dedicated Linux system. I do not have the CD's to install OSX. So I would prefer to just install Linux. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know, if you have a friend with a Mac you can make a Mac boot USB, which will install the OS...